# Error: React component type is invalid in LoginScreen.test.js file. Expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, react-native-testing-library

**LoginScreen.test.js**

```
    import { Text } from 'react-native';
    it("Login_Screen_should_render_correctly", () => {
     const { toJSON } = render(<Text >hey</Text>)                               
      expect(toJSON).toMatchSnapshot();
       expect(true).toEqual(true);
     });
```

**Error**

```
  at printWarning (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:220:30)
```

at error (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:196:5)
at Object.createElementWithValidation [as createElement] (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:2215:7)
at Object.createElement (src/components/LoginScreen/LoginScreen.test.js:7:31)

**package.json**

```
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^12.0.0",
"babel-jest": "^22.4.3",
"detox": "^20.5.0",
"eslint": "7.14.0",
"jest": "^29.5.0",
"jest-circus": "^29.5.0",
"jest-environment-jsdom-fifteen": "^1.0.2",
"react": "17.0.1",
"react-native": "0.64.1",
```

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
preset: 'react-native',
moduleNameMapper: {
    "\\.(png|jpg|svg)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/images.js"
},
setupFiles: ['./jest.setup.js'],
```

};

**Expected outcome:**
*The test case Login_Screen_should_render_correctly should pass without any errors.*